# Using Basicprimitive with Angularjs Error: jQuery(...).orgDiagram is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, html

I am trying to convert this sample http://www.basicprimitives.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=71&Itemid=116&lang=en into my angular application.
But every time I get below error

```
TypeError: jQuery(...).orgDiagram is not a function
    at link (http://localhost:32150/app/BasicPrimitives.js:14:45)
    at http://localhost:32150/scripts/angular.js:7094:44
    at nodeLinkFn (http://localhost:32150/scripts/angular.js:6692:13)
    at compositeLinkFn (http://localhost:32150/scripts/angular.js:6086:13)
    at compositeLinkFn (http://localhost:32150/scripts/angular.js:6089:13)
    at nodeLinkFn (http://localhost:32150/scripts/angular.js:6686:24)
    at compositeLinkFn (http://localhost:32150/scripts/angular.js:6086:13)
    at compositeLinkFn (http://localhost:32150/scripts/angular.js:6089:13)
    at compositeLinkFn (http://localhost:32150/scripts/angular.js:6089:13)
    at compositeLinkFn (http://localhost:32150/scripts/angular.js:6089:13) 
        <div bp-org-diagram="" data-options="myOptions" data-on-highlight-changed="onMyHighlightChanged()" data-on-cursor-changed="onMyCursorChanged()" style="width: 800px; height: 600px; border-style: dotted; border-width: 1px;" class="ng-isolate-scope"> (anonymous function)
        @ angular.js:10046$get
        @ angular.js:7343(anonymous function)
        @ config.exceptionHandler.js:21nodeLinkFn
        @ angular.js:6695compositeLinkFn
        @ angular.js:6086compositeLinkFn
        @ angular.js:6089nodeLinkFn
        @ angular.js:6686compositeLinkFn
        @ angular.js:6086compositeLinkFn
        @ angular.js:6089compositeLinkFn
        @ angular.js:6089compositeLinkFn
        @ angular.js:6089compositeLinkFn
        @ angular.js:6089nodeLinkFn 
        @ angular.js:6686compositeLinkFn 
        @ angular.js:6086publicLinkFn 
        @ angular.js:5982link 
        @ angular-route.js:919nodeLinkFn 
        @ angular.js:6692compositeLinkFn 
        @ angular.js:6086publicLinkFn 
        @ angular.js:5982$get.boundTranscludeFn 
        @ angular.js:6106controllersBoundTransclude 
        @ angular.js:6713update 
        @ angular-route.js:869$get.Scope.$broadcast 
        @ angular.js:12937(anonymous function) 
        @ angular-route.js:550deferred.promise.then.wrappedCallback 
        @ angular.js:11546deferred.promise.then.wrappedCallback 
        @ angular.js:11546(anonymous function)
        @ angular.js:11632$get.Scope.$eval 
        @ angular.js:12658$get.Scope.$digest 
        @ angular.js:12470$get.Scope.$apply 
        @ angular.js:12762done 
        @ angular.js:8357completeRequest 
        @ angular.js:8571xhr.onreadystatechange 
        @ angular.js:8510
angular.js:10046 [app]  [HT Error] jQuery(...).orgDiagram is not a function Object {exception: TypeError: jQuery(...).orgDiagram is not a function
at link (http://localhost:32150/app/BasicPri…, cause: "<div bp-org-diagram="" data-options="myOptions" da…ed; border-width: 1px;" class="ng-isolate-scope">"}
```

If I take the above sample its working fine. in my main app module I have several other modules injected. but on injection of basic primitive module I get above error

App Module :

```
var app = angular.module('app', [

        // Angular modules 
        'ngAnimate',        // animations
        'ngRoute',          // routing
        'ngSanitize',       // sanitizes html bindings (ex: sidebar.js)
        'ui.grid',
        // Custom modules 
        'common',           // common functions, logger, spinner
        'common.bootstrap', // bootstrap dialog wrapper functions
        'LocalStorageModule',
        'angular-loading-bar',        
        'angularFileUpload',
        'BasicPrimitives',
        // 3rd Party Modules
        'ui.bootstrap'      // ui-bootstrap (ex: carousel, pagination, dialog)

    ]);
```

HTML:

```
<div id="centerpanel" style="overflow: hidden; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; border: 0px;">
    <div bp-org-diagram data-options="myOptions" data-on-highlight-changed="onMyHighlightChanged()" data-on-cursor-changed="onMyCursorChanged()"
        style="width: 800px; height: 600px; border-style: dotted; border-width: 1px;"></div>
</div>
```

JsController:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    var controllerId = 'orgdepartmentJsController';
    angular.module('app').controller(controllerId, ['$scope', 'common', '$location','ngAuthSettings', 'orgdepartmentJsService', orgdepartmentJsController]);

    function orgdepartmentJsController($scope, common, $location,ngAuthSettings, orgdepartmentJsService) {
        var getLogFn = common.logger.getLogFn;
        var log = getLogFn(controllerId);

        var vm = this;
        $scope.title = 'Departments';

        activate();
        $scope.index = 10;
        $scope.Message = "";
        $scope.orgdepartmentList = [];
        $scope.editMode = 'List';
        $scope.objorgdepartment = {};

        $scope.addNew = function () {
            $scope.editMode = 'New';
        };
        $scope.cancel = function () {
            getorgdepartment();
            $scope.editMode = 'List';            
        };
        $scope.save = function (objorgdepartment) {
            $scope.editMode = 'List';
            orgdepartmentJsService.save(objorgdepartment).then(function (results) {

            }, function (error) {
                alert(error.data.message);
            });
        };


        function getorgdepartment() {
            orgdepartmentJsService.getall().then(function (results) {
                //debugger;
                $scope.orgdepartmentList = results.data;
                $("#grid").kendoGrid({
                    toolbar: ["excel"],
                    excel: {
                        fileName: "Kendo UI Grid Export.xlsx",
                        //proxyURL: "//demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/export",
                        filterable: true
                    },
                    dataSource: {

                        data: $scope.orgdepartmentList,
                        schema: {
                            model: {
                                fields: {
                                    DepartmentName: { type: "string" },
                                    Description: { type: "string" }
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        pageSize: 20
                    },
                    height: 550,
                    scrollable: true,
                    sortable: true,
                    filterable: true,
                    pageable: {
                        input: true,
                        numeric: false
                    },

                    columns: [

                        { field: "departmentName", title: "DepartmentName", width: "130px" },
                        { field: "description", title: "Description", width: "130px" }
                    ]
                });




            }, function (error) {
                // debugger;
                alert(error.data.message);
            });
        }
        function activate() {
            common.activateController([], controllerId)
                .then(function () { log('Activated Departments View'); });
            getorgdepartment();
        }
        var serviceBase = ngAuthSettings.apiServiceBaseUri;

        //OrgChart

        $scope.orgChart = function () {
            $scope.editMode = 'OrgChart';

        }
        $scope.index = 10;
        $scope.Message = "";

        var options = {};

        var items = [
            new primitives.orgdiagram.ItemConfig({
                id: 0,
                parent: null,
                title: "Scott Aasrud",
                description: "Root",
                phone: "1 (416) 001-4567",
                email: "scott.aasrud@mail.com",
                image: "demo/images/photos/a.png",
                itemTitleColor: primitives.common.Colors.RoyalBlue
            }),
            new primitives.orgdiagram.ItemConfig({
                id: 1,
                parent: 0,
                title: "Ted Lucas",
                description: "Left",
                phone: "1 (416) 002-4567",
                email: "ted.lucas@mail.com",
                image: "demo/images/photos/b.png",
                itemTitleColor: primitives.common.Colors.RoyalBlue
            }),
            new primitives.orgdiagram.ItemConfig({
                id: 2,
                parent: 0,
                title: "Joao Stuger",
                description: "Right",
                phone: "1 (416) 003-4567",
                email: "joao.stuger@mail.com",
                image: "demo/images/photos/c.png",
                itemTitleColor: primitives.common.Colors.RoyalBlue
            }),
            new primitives.orgdiagram.ItemConfig({
                id: 3,
                parent: 2,
                title: "Hidden Node",
                phone: "1 (416) 004-4567",
                email: "hidden.node@mail.com",
                description: "Dotted Node",
                image: "demo/images/photos/e.png",
                itemTitleColor: primitives.common.Colors.PaleVioletRed
            })
        ];

        options.items = items;
        options.cursorItem = 0;
        options.highlightItem = 0;
        options.hasSelectorCheckbox = primitives.common.Enabled.True;
        options.templates = [getContactTemplate()];
        options.defaultTemplateName = "contactTemplate";

        $scope.myOptions = options;

        $scope.setCursorItem = function (item) {
            $scope.myOptions.cursorItem = item;
        };

        $scope.setHighlightItem = function (item) {
            $scope.myOptions.highlightItem = item;
        };

        $scope.deleteItem = function (index) {
            $scope.myOptions.items.splice(index, 1);
        }

        $scope.addItem = function (index, parent) {
            var id = $scope.index++;
            $scope.myOptions.items.splice(index, 0, new primitives.orgdiagram.ItemConfig({
                id: id,
                parent: parent,
                title: "New title " + id,
                description: "New description " + id,
                image: "demo/images/photos/b.png"
            }));
        }

        $scope.onMyCursorChanged = function () {
            $scope.Message = "onMyCursorChanged";
        }

        $scope.onMyHighlightChanged = function () {
            $scope.Message = "onMyHighlightChanged";
        }

        function getContactTemplate() {
            var result = new primitives.orgdiagram.TemplateConfig();
            result.name = "contactTemplate";

            result.itemSize = new primitives.common.Size(220, 120);
            result.minimizedItemSize = new primitives.common.Size(5, 5);
            result.minimizedItemCornerRadius = 5;
            result.highlightPadding = new primitives.common.Thickness(2, 2, 2, 2);


            var itemTemplate = jQuery(
              '<div class="bp-item bp-corner-all bt-item-frame">'
                + '<div name="titleBackground" class="bp-item bp-corner-all bp-title-frame" style="background:{{itemTitleColor}};top: 2px; left: 2px; width: 216px; height: 20px;">'
                    + '<div name="title" class="bp-item bp-title" style="top: 3px; left: 6px; width: 208px; height: 18px;">{{itemConfig.title}}</div>'
                + '</div>'
                + '<div class="bp-item bp-photo-frame" style="top: 26px; left: 2px; width: 50px; height: 60px;">'
                    + '<img name="photo" src="{{itemConfig.image}}" style="height: 60px; width:50px;" />'
                + '</div>'
                + '<div name="phone" class="bp-item" style="top: 26px; left: 56px; width: 162px; height: 18px; font-size: 12px;">{{itemConfig.phone}}</div>'
                + '<div class="bp-item" style="top: 44px; left: 56px; width: 162px; height: 18px; font-size: 12px;"><a name="email" href="mailto::{{itemConfig.email}}" target="_top">{{itemConfig.email}}</a></div>'
                + '<div name="description" class="bp-item" style="top: 62px; left: 56px; width: 162px; height: 36px; font-size: 10px;">{{itemConfig.description}}</div>'
            + '</div>'
            ).css({
                width: result.itemSize.width + "px",
                height: result.itemSize.height + "px"
            }).addClass("bp-item bp-corner-all bt-item-frame");
            result.itemTemplate = itemTemplate.wrap('<div>').parent().html();

            return result;
        }


    }
})();
```

Script Links on Index Page

```
<script src="scripts/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/primitives.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/angular-file-upload.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/angular-ui/ui-bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script src="scripts/angular-cookies.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/angular-local-storage.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/loading-bar.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/ui-grid-unstable.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/toastr.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/moment.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.10.0.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/spin.js"></script>

    <script src="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2015.2.805/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2015.2.805/js/jszip.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2015.2.805/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>


    <!--<script src="app/login.js"></script>-->
    <!-- Bootstrapping -->
    <script src="app/BasicPrimitives.js"></script>
    <script src="app/app.js"></script>
```

Comment: How do you expect us to fix a bug in code we can't see?

Comment: what would you like me to add here?

Comment: Yes sure add here @waqarhabib. I can't see invisible things.

Comment: @waqarhabib: The code that is causing the error.

Comment: Problem is in html : directive  bp-org-diagram its empty every time and the basicprimitive module not injected

Comment: It might be related to order of loading the scripts.

Comment: No script are order properly I was following this sample :http://www.basicprimitives.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=71&Itemid=116&lang=en

Comment: did you include the basicprimitives library itself? `<script type="text/javascript" src="demo/js/primitives.min.js?206"></script>`?

Comment: @jorg yes It is there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are referring two jquery versions in your scripts. Please remove following reference and hopefully it will solve your problem.

```
 <script src="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2015.2.805/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
```